# C - How to check CRC?

Tags: c, crc

I want to check CRC for a data packet. The data packet is in hex. They provided the CRC check 'C' code in protocol document. Below is the code.

```
static const U16 crctab16[] =
{
0X0000, 0X1189, 0X2312, 0X329B, 0X4624, 0X57AD, 0X6536, 0X74BF,
0X8C48, 0X9DC1, 0XAF5A, 0XBED3, 0XCA6C, 0XDBE5, 0XE97E, 0XF8F7,
0X1081, 0X0108, 0X3393, 0X221A, 0X56A5, 0X472C, 0X75B7, 0X643E,
0X9CC9, 0X8D40, 0XBFDB, 0XAE52, 0XDAED, 0XCB64, 0XF9FF, 0XE876,
0X2102, 0X308B, 0X0210, 0X1399, 0X6726, 0X76AF, 0X4434, 0X55BD,
0XAD4A, 0XBCC3, 0X8E58, 0X9FD1, 0XEB6E, 0XFAE7, 0XC87C, 0XD9F5,
0X3183, 0X200A, 0X1291, 0X0318, 0X77A7, 0X662E, 0X54B5, 0X453C,
0XBDCB, 0XAC42, 0X9ED9, 0X8F50, 0XFBEF, 0XEA66, 0XD8FD, 0XC974,
0X4204, 0X538D, 0X6116, 0X709F, 0X0420, 0X15A9, 0X2732, 0X36BB,
0XCE4C, 0XDFC5, 0XED5E, 0XFCD7, 0X8868, 0X99E1, 0XAB7A, 0XBAF3,
0X5285, 0X430C, 0X7197, 0X601E, 0X14A1, 0X0528, 0X37B3, 0X263A,
0XDECD, 0XCF44, 0XFDDF, 0XEC56, 0X98E9, 0X8960, 0XBBFB, 0XAA72,
0X6306, 0X728F, 0X4014, 0X519D, 0X2522, 0X34AB, 0X0630, 0X17B9,
0XEF4E, 0XFEC7, 0XCC5C, 0XDDD5, 0XA96A, 0XB8E3, 0X8A78, 0X9BF1,
0X7387, 0X620E, 0X5095, 0X411C, 0X35A3, 0X242A, 0X16B1, 0X0738,
0XFFCF, 0XEE46, 0XDCDD, 0XCD54, 0XB9EB, 0XA862, 0X9AF9, 0X8B70,
0X8408, 0X9581, 0XA71A, 0XB693, 0XC22C, 0XD3A5, 0XE13E, 0XF0B7,
0X0840, 0X19C9, 0X2B52, 0X3ADB, 0X4E64, 0X5FED, 0X6D76, 0X7CFF,
0X9489, 0X8500, 0XB79B, 0XA612, 0XD2AD, 0XC324, 0XF1BF, 0XE036,
0X18C1, 0X0948, 0X3BD3, 0X2A5A, 0X5EE5, 0X4F6C, 0X7DF7, 0X6C7E,
0XA50A, 0XB483, 0X8618, 0X9791, 0XE32E, 0XF2A7, 0XC03C, 0XD1B5,
0X2942, 0X38CB, 0X0A50, 0X1BD9, 0X6F66, 0X7EEF, 0X4C74, 0X5DFD,
0XB58B, 0XA402, 0X9699, 0X8710, 0XF3AF, 0XE226, 0XD0BD, 0XC134,
0X39C3, 0X284A, 0X1AD1, 0X0B58, 0X7FE7, 0X6E6E, 0X5CF5, 0X4D7C,
0XC60C, 0XD785, 0XE51E, 0XF497, 0X8028, 0X91A1, 0XA33A, 0XB2B3,
0X4A44, 0X5BCD, 0X6956, 0X78DF, 0X0C60, 0X1DE9, 0X2F72, 0X3EFB,
0XD68D, 0XC704, 0XF59F, 0XE416, 0X90A9, 0X8120, 0XB3BB, 0XA232,
0X5AC5, 0X4B4C, 0X79D7, 0X685E, 0X1CE1, 0X0D68, 0X3FF3, 0X2E7A,
0XE70E, 0XF687, 0XC41C, 0XD595, 0XA12A, 0XB0A3, 0X8238, 0X93B1,
0X6B46, 0X7ACF, 0X4854, 0X59DD, 0X2D62, 0X3CEB, 0X0E70, 0X1FF9,
0XF78F, 0XE606, 0XD49D, 0XC514, 0XB1AB, 0XA022, 0X92B9, 0X8330,
0X7BC7, 0X6A4E, 0X58D5, 0X495C, 0X3DE3, 0X2C6A, 0X1EF1, 0X0F78,
};
// calculate the 16-bit CRC of data with predetermined length.
U16 GetCrc16(const U8* pData, int nLength)
{
U16 fcs = 0xffff; // initialization
while(nLength>0){
fcs = (fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *pData) & 0xff];
nLength--;
pData++;
} return ~
fcs; // negated
}
```

Below code is main function with passed hex values and lenght of data.

```
int main()
{
const uint8_t* pData[]={'0x16', '0x80', '0x10', '0x00', '0x01', '0xA9',     '0x67', '0x44', '0x57', '0x58' ,'0x58', '0x2C', '0x30' ,'0x30', '0x30', '0x30',     '0x30', '0x30', '0x23', '0x00', '0xA0'};
printf("%x",GetCrc16(pData, 21));
return 0;
}
```

From above passed value, the expecting CRC is "**07 AE**"
But i'm getting incorrect CRC. I tried hex formats like '0x16' and '16'. I think the format i passed in "pData" is wrong. What would be the format i have to passed in "pData"?

Thanks

Comment: `const uint8_t* pData[]` <-- did you mean `const uint8_t pData[]` (without the `*`)?

Comment: A quick glance reveals another mistake: `'0x80'`: you shouldn't be quoting the values. See the declaration of `crctab16`. No quotes there.

Comment: No. The hex values i gave in  pData array. Is i have to give '0x16' or only '16' or 'x16'? I tried all of it. no use.

Comment: did you try `0x16` without quotes?

Comment: @ArjunShankar I tried without quote. I'm getting 'adf8'. expecting value is  '07AE'

Comment: https://ideone.com/jwvy36 outputs `62d`.

Comment: Hi @mch Let me check. I get back... Thnx...

Comment: @mch  its working. Thank you....

Comment: So basically your statement that "the expecting CRC is "07 AE" But i'm getting incorrect CRC" is wrong, and this question can be closed as "not reproducible"?

Comment: Try the data without quotes..

Comment: @user25770 How did you determine your expected value of '07AE'?

Comment: I was wrong,  '07AE' is wrong CRC.